# BiodiversityR package for R error message for Mac

Tags: r, macos, error-handling, hmisc

I am having a series of problems and receiving error messages installing BiodiversityR in a Mac computer

I type 
`install.packages("BiodiversityR")` 
`install.packages("Rcmdr")`
`install.packages("dismo")`
`install.packages("RcmdrMisc")`

Although all installations seem to run fine, when I try: 
`require(BiodiversityR)` 
`require(Rcmdr)`
then I get an Error: package or namespace load failed for 'RcmdrMisc':
object 'print.rcorr' is not exported by 'namespace:Hmisc'

Can someone advise me on how to solving this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by uninstalling R and turning off my computer to clear the local memory. I then turned on my computer and reinstalled R. Then I installed BiodiversityR, uninstalled Hmisc, which it installed automatically with BiodiversityR, reinstalled Hmisc, reinstalled BiodiversityR, and it solved my problem.